# Code error when trying to print out the node of a LinkedList

Tags: c++, printing, indexing, linked-list

Hey im basically trying to print out the corresponding node with its element.  But im getting an error: `Error  1   error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'DoublyLinkedListNode<Datatype> *' to 'int &'`
Ive tried a few things like changing the Index functions return type but so far ive had no joy. 
Can anyone help me fix this?

Here is my code:

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           Print.
//  Description:    Prints the elements from the list along with its index.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void Print(DoublyLinkedList<int>& p_list)
    {
    //Set up a new Iterator.
    DoublyLinkedListIterator<int> itr = getIterator();
    for(itr.Start(); itr.Valid(); itr.Forth())
        {
        cout <<"Index: "<<itr.Index() << "Element: " << itr.Item() << "\n";
        }
    cout << endl;


    }
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Class:  DoublyLinkedIterator.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class Datatype>
class DoublyLinkedListIterator
{
public:
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Member Vairables.
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    DoublyLinkedListNode<Datatype>* m_node;
    DoublyLinkedList<Datatype>* m_list;
    DoublyLinkedListIterator(DoublyLinkedList<Datatype>* p_list= 0, DoublyLinkedListNode<Datatype>* p_node= 0)
    {
        m_list= p_list;
        m_node= p_node;
    }

// ------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           Start
//  Description:    Resets the iterator to the beginning of the list.
//  Arguments:      None.
//  Return Value:   None.
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
    void Start()
    {
        if(m_list!= 0)
            m_node= m_list -> m_head;
    }

// ----------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           End
//  Description:    Resets the iterator to the end of the list
//  Arguments:      None.
//  Return Value:   None.
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
    void End()
    {
        if(m_list!= 0)
            m_node = m_list->m_tail;
    }

// ----------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           Forth
//  Description:    Moves the iterator forward by one position
//  Arguments:      None.
//  Return Value:   None.
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
    void Forth()
    {
        if(m_node!= 0)
            m_node= m_node->m_next;
    }

// ----------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           Back
//  Description:    Moves the iterator backward by one position.
//  Arguments:      None.
//  Return Value:   None.
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
    void Back()
    {
        if(m_node!= 0)
            m_node = m_node->m_prev;
    }


// ----------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           Item
//  Description:    Gets the item that the iterator is pointing to.
//  Arguments:      None.
//  Return Value:   Reference to the data in the node.
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
    Datatype& Item()
    {
        return m_node->m_data;
    }


// ----------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Name:           Index
    //  Description:    Gets the index that the iterator is pointing to.
    //  Arguments:      None.
    //  Return Value:   Reference to the data in the node.
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------
        Datatype& Index()
        {
            return m_node;
        }
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           Valid
//  Description:    Determines if the node is valid.
//  Arguments:      None.
//  Return Value:   true if valid
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
    bool Valid()
    {
        return (m_node!= 0);
    }
```

Comment: IMHO, code shown is not complete, hard to spot errors.

Comment: What line of code is the error referring to?  I don't think it's in your question.

Comment: What line is that error on? I don't even see a function returning an int&

Comment: The error is referring to the cout line in the for loop in the print function.

Comment: @ArgumentNullException  If i take the index() out of the cout there are no errors.  Index() is the only thing with the problem :S

Comment: Sorry, I got confused lol.  Index() is returning a pointer to DoublyLinkedListNode<Datatype> but you have the function declared to return Datatype &.  So the value being returned by Index() in the address of m_node as a reference to an int.

Comment: Are you trying to return the value of m_node, the doublyLinkedList m_node, or an index to an item in doublyLinkedList m_node?  I don't see any data member called index.

Comment: @ArgumentNullException if i change index() return type to DoublyLinkedListNode<Datatype> i get an operator conversion error :S

Comment: Well i want to have the index of the elements and i think tht returning the node that the iterator is pointing to will achieve this.  Beacause in the for loop the itr goes through the nodes and claims there data by printing out item so i reckon getting the node its pointing to is the way to go :)

Comment: I'm not suggesting you change the return type.  I think you're returning the wrong value.  A doublylinkedlist does not track index (from what I remember).  What the iterator returns is pointer to the item.

Comment: Ohhh i see. As far as i can see there is no other variable to possibly get the index.

Comment: Correct.  You have to manually print them by using a variable i and increment it while you traverse the list.

Comment: @ArgumentNullException  Worked like a charm.  Ill post the answer and thank you for helping me explain :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically i was trying to use m_node as the index which i was told wasnt the way to do and to increase a variable during the for loop in the print method.  This worked correctly
Here is the code:

```
void Print(DoublyLinkedList<int>& p_list)
    {
        int index = 0;
    //Set up a new Iterator.
    DoublyLinkedListIterator<int> itr = getIterator();
    for(itr.Start(); itr.Valid(); itr.Forth())
        {
        index++;
        cout <<"Index: "<< index << "Element: " << itr.Item() << "\n";
        }
    cout <<"Number of Elements in the List: " << m_count << endl;


    }
```